# Failed to sign in with Google: 302 Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm doing authentication through google, getting url from backend and making post:

```
  Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>['email']);

try {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  if (googleUser != null) {
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;


    final response = await Dio().post(
      googleUrl,
      data: {'token': googleAuth.accessToken},
      options: kOptions,
    );

    debugPrint("Google Sign-In server response status code: ${response.statusCode}");
    debugPrint("Google Sign-In server response body: ${response.data}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      saveToken(response.data["token"]);
      return response.data["token"];
    } else {
      throw Exception("${response.statusCode}  ${response.data}");
    }
  } else {
    throw Exception();
  }
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint('Google Sign-In error: ${e.toString()}');
  throw e;
}
```

}

```
 Future<void> signInWithGoogle({
    required BuildContext context
}) async {
    emit(const AuthenticationState.initial());
    try {
      final token = await authenticationService.signInWithGoogle();
      if (token != null) {
        emit(const AuthenticationState.authenticated());
      } else {
        emit(AuthenticationState.error(
            getLocalizedString(context,'error_sign_google')));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Google Sign-In error: ${e.toString()}");
      if (e is PlatformException) {
        debugPrint('PlatformException details: ${e.details}');
      }
      emit(AuthenticationState.error(e.toString()));
    }
  }



SignInButton(
              buttonType: ButtonType.google,
              buttonText: getLocalizedString(
             context, 'sign_in_google'),
              onPressed: () {
          context.read<AuthenticationCubit>().signInWithGoogle(context: context),},),
```

google opens, i'm making authentication, everything is successful. but it doesn't register anything. and getting this error:I/flutter ( 7717): Google Sign-In error: Exception: 302
I/flutter ( 7717): Google Sign-In error: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
I/flutter ( 7717): PlatformException details: null